# Comment traduire "out of" ?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Ceci provient de la page 72 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> With the verb prendre, **dans** means *out of*.
>
> Prenez deux dollars **dans** mon sac. = Take two dollars *out of* my bag.

Je ne peux pas préciser pourquoi, mais **dans** m'est imprévu et me paraît insolite. Prière de le détailler ?

Du reste, quelles sont d'autres manières d'exprimer ceci avec et sans le verbe prendre?

1. Prenez deux dollars hors de mon sac ?
2. Sortez deux dollars hors de ??? mon sac ?
3. Faites sortir deux dollars hors de ??? mon sac ?

**Supplément daté le 3 février 2014** Grâce à Laure, sa réponse montre un autre exemple :

> Comparer « de » et « sur » dans `4.` « Prends-les de l'étagère. »,`5.` « Prends-les sur l'étagère. »

Je suis désarçonné et je voudrais vérifier les différences entre 4. et 5. Est-ce que Laure voulait dire que  `4.` s'applique aux 2 vertes étoiles et `5.` aux 3 rouges coeurs ?  Prière de me corriger.

[image]

Comment: Question mal posée. La question ne porte pas sur la traduction de *out of* (dont d'ailleurs tu ne ne sembles pas comprendre l'emploi en anglais) et dont tu aurais pu [trouver des traductions facilement](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of) et aussi [ici](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/out%20of) sans le demander ici, mais tu veux savoir quel verbe employer en français, et avec quelle préposition, pour exprimer ton idée.

Comment: @Laure: Merci de votre commentaire. SVP, prière d'amender mon OP dans l'intention de l'améliorer ? *out of* signifie de l'intérieur jusqu'à l'extérieur, non ? A quel "emploi en anglais" traitez-vous ? Je suis égaré.

Comment: J'ai complété ma réponse en prenant des exemples sur l'illustration.

Comment: @Laure: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Prenez deux dollars hors de mon sac.

C'est grammatical mais ça signifie que tu dis à quelqu'un de prendre deux dollars qui sont « hors de » (= pas dans) ton sac.

La préposition de lieu qui suit prendre sert à désigner l'emplacement de l'objet qui est COD. Donc dans le cas que tu envisages on peut dire :

> Prenez deux dollars de mon sac.

ou

> Prenez deux dollars dans mon sac.

Les prépositions *de* et *dans* conviennent toutes les deux pour exprimer ce que tu veux dire, avec une très légère nuance qui ne sera pas forcément pertinente dans la majorité des cas.
**De** peut être ressenti comme lié au verbe et exprimant l'origine du mouvement.
**Dans** est lié uniquement au complément de lieu et exprime l'emplacement de l'objet avant le mouvement de « sortir ».

Comparer « de » et « sur » dans les phrases suivantes (voir l'illustration dans la question) : 
« Prends les étoiles de l'étagère. »
« Prends les étoiles sur l'étagère. »
« Prends les cœurs de l'étagère. »
« Prends-les coeurs dans l'étagère. »

#### 2. Sortez deux dollars hors de mon sac.

C'est grammatical et ça pourrait se comprendre mais le « hors » est inutile car déjà exprimé dans sortir. « De » est la préposition qui introduit le complément de lieu pour indiquer la provenance.

> Sortez deux dollars de mon sac.

#### 3. Faites sortir deux dollars hors de mon sac.

Là aussi c'est grammatical mais le sens n'est pas celui que tu recherches. Tu pourrais demander ça à un magicien qui d'un coup de baguette magique donnerait mouvement à deux dollars qui sortiraient tout seuls de ton sac.